# Seeking explanation for WPF DispatcherHooks accounting

Tags: wpf, dispatcher

I am trying to use [DispatcherHooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherhooks(v=vs.100).aspx) to get a measure of the queue length of the UI thread dispatcher with code similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260857/querying-the-dispatcher-queue-length). I further refined the hooks to track operations by priority and am finding that the number of completions + aborts is far greater than the number of posted operations at some of the priorities.

For example, in a five second sampling interval, I see 7 operations posted at the Background priority, but over 1000 completions.  For the Render priority, it's almost as if each post results in two completions.

The other categories look reasonable, but lacking an explanation for Render / Background, it casts a shadow on the accuracy/relevance of the other priorities. It's not a matter of priorities changing either, since the overall totals do not mesh.

Can anyone explain what I'm seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out by factoring in the "Inactive" priority.  It looks like when many (all?) of the Background and Render operations get queued, their priority on posting is "inactive", but their priority on Completion reflects the actual priority of the operation, so the overall picture of queue length is reasonable, but looks like I can't get the granularity by priority (which for my scenario is probably ok).